# Cron job - permission denied creating a file

Tags: permissions, cron

I have a cron job:

```
#!/bin/bash 
fn=db.backup.$(date +%m-%d-%y).sql
mysqldump -uMyUsr -pMyPass --add-drop-table dbName> $fn
find ./ -name '*.Z' -type f -mtime +7 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

I get an error:

```
/backup.sh: line 3: db.backup.10-24-12.sql: Permission denied
db.backup.10-24-12.sql: No such file or directory
find: ./conf: Permission denied
find: ./pd: Permission denied
```

It looks like whatever process is running cron doesn't have permissions to create a file or to run 'find' command.

Comment: what are the permissions of the directory it is running in?

Comment: the backup.sh is running in 'sqlbackup' directory that has 777 or rwx for all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use:

```
fn=/full/path/to/db.backup.$(date +%m-%d-%y).sql
```

or

```
cd /full/path/to/
```

before you export the database

unless your cronjob looks like:

```
* * * * * cd /full/path/to && backup.sh
```